# Elastic beanstalk scalling trigger upper threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am a newbie in aws. I want to know what is data points in elastic beanstalk scaling trigger upper threshold section.
[image]

Is this a memory limit or cpu utilization?
What is its unit?
What happen when i increase or decrease this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers work over metrics provided by CloudWatch.

CloudWatch is a system that measures different items, tipically every 1 minute. (some are every 5 minutes)

Each of these measurements is considered a "data point"

In your example look in the same page, there it says if is a CPU utilisation or other measure.

If you change that value you will change the threshold necessary to launch another instance in EB